# Simple Method to Plot Columns in Pandas Dataframe on Different rows of plot?

Tags: pandas, plot, plotly, seaborn, python-ggplot

Is there a simple method to plot all columns on different rows/ tiles, with a shared X-axis? Ido not want to go deep into matplotlib subplots for each new figure; I'm looking for something simple that allows me to view all data in the dataframe easily. I feel like there is a simple flag or option in Pandas or Seaborn I'm missing.

A simple dataframe.plot() in pandas gives all variables stacked:
[image]

I want a simple approach (not many lines of matplotlib figure building) that creates a new facet for each variable (column) in the dataframe, with separate Y-axes, but shared X-axes.

Maybe something I'm overlooking in ggplot2?

Goal - something like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you post your DataFrame for us to reproduce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(4,1))
```

It seems to generate exactly what you wanted.

If you want the labels to be outside of the plot, you can do some handling after the df.plot:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=(20,4)))
df.plot(ax=ax, subplots=True, layout=(4,1)) # ax=ax points df.plot to fig
for each in fig.axes: # You can still modify these axes!
    each.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

This will set the legend outside of the plot to the right, in the same process like you would set any other legend.

Comment: @EHB Here's an extended version (with code examples!) of the very poorly documented pandas functions:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

Comment: As a similar follow-up - have you found a good solution for putting the legend OUTSIDE the plot w/o resorting to base-level matplotlib manipulation?

Comment: AMAZING!! Have read so many SO posts with very complicated answers. You should answer this on those!! Many thanks.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be possible to call `plt.tight_layout()` using your method above. How else could one keep labels in the legend from getting cut off (longer labels)?

Comment: @EHB I've tried `tight_layout` before and it never worked for me even on a plain field.. I try to stay away from that now ... You can fix your `ax` positions to allow for more space for labels to show up without using `tight_layout`